# Not able to view video in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, video, google-chrome

I am trying to view a video in safari and it says there is a plugin missing. The message I get is:

```
This page has content that requires an Internet plug-in.
This page contains content of “application/x-vlc-plugin” type. You do not have the plug-in required to view this content.
```

I cannot view this video on Chrome as well.
Please let me know what I can do to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need the VLC plugin, available on [VLC download page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html).

Comment: Actually I had already done that. Just needed to restart the browser. Thanks.